# Reload my view controller after Core Data delete operation

Tags: ios, core-data, refresh, nsmanagedobject

I have one summary page controller where I display all users from database file.

I'm using Core Data environment. In this page I have one button to delete all users from db. This is working fine but I'm not able to reflect those changes in current screen. I need to reload my view controller in order to reflect those changes on screen.

Here is what I do.

```
for (NSManagedObject * user in users) {
    [delegate.managedObjectContext deleteObject:user];
}

NSError *saveError = nil;
[delegate.managedObjectContext save:&saveError];
```

How to refresh my current screen?

Comment: After deletion immediately again call or select database all values its automatically refresh your screen.

Comment: i'v done all it in viewDeadLoad method...i tried to call it again after deletion from database, bt it is not working!

Comment: Delete all objects from you datasource of the view controller and call `setNeedsDisplay` on the view.

Comment: Provide some other details (and code). In particular, what do you mean with *I've done all it in viewDidLoad method*? Thanks.